# Pandas: how can I use map on a column in a pandas dataframe to create a new column? Having trouble using a lambda function to do this

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, collections, counter

I have a data set containing strings in 1 column that I want to count the most common character and put that character in a new column. I also want another column that contains the proportion of the string the character represents.

The method I want to use on each string is as follows:

```py
sequence = 'ACCCCTGGC'
char_i_want = collections.Counter(sequence).most_common(1)[0] # for the character
value_i_want = collections.Counter(sequence).most_common(1)[1] / len(sequence) # for the proportion
```

I understand the result of most_common is a tuple, but when I try this in a python shell, I need to do `collections.Counter(sequence).most_common(1)[0][0]` to access the 0th element of the tuple, the tuple being the 0th element of the returned list. When I tried implementing that, it still didn't work.

Here is how I attempted to do it:

```py
def common_char(sequence):
    return Counter(sequence).most_common(1)[0][0]

def char_freq(sequence):
    return Counter(sequence).most_common(1)[0][1] / len(sequence)

data = pd.read_csv('final_file_noidx.csv')
data['most_common_ref'] = data['REF'].map(lambda x: common_char(x))
data['most_common_ref_frac'] = data['REF'].map(lambda x: char_freq(x))
```

I am greeted by this error message: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

Comment: some values in your `data['REF']` are `float`. Just double check it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
data['most_common_ref'] = data['REF'].map(lambda x: common_char(x), na_action='ignore')
data['most_common_ref_frac'] = data['REF'].map(lambda x: char_freq(x), na_action='ignore')
```

Needed to ignore NaNs, thanks Andy L.

Comment: I am glad that you figured it out :)